# A tricky recursive bash alias? install at first use

Tags: bash, alias

I wonder if this is possible, make an alias, that does a sudo apt-get to the command if it is not there already, and then realiases itself to stop making this changes.

Thus I am looking for this semantics

```
smartalias top = 
     if (not installed htop) then 
        install htop; 
     alias top htop; 
     top
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shell function:

```
top() {
    if ! type htop &>/dev/null; then
        sudo apt-get install htop
    fi
    htop
}
```

Comment: Possibly `command htop` to avoid that hilarious loop when the function is named the same as the command...

Answer (score 1):

Bash has an existing feature to take care of that: [`command_not_found_handle`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution). This is a hook that is executed when bash tries to execute an external command. Zsh has [`command_not_found_handler`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html#index-command_005fnot_005ffound_005fhandler) which is similar. Many distributions
set up bash so that it will offer to install the relevant package if you try to execute a command that doesn't exist. For example, you seem to be on a Debian derivative, so install the [`command-not-found` package](http://packages.debian.org/command-not-found). This mechanism is equivalent to setting up the alias you want for every command provided by the distribution.

Comment: `command-not-found` can be useful but note that it will add annoying delays and waste valuable screen space every time you make a typo on a command name.  I'm prone to such typos so I always end up purging that package (IIRC it gets installed by default on new debian and ubuntu etc systems)